# Running raco on the Windows command line

Tags: windows, powershell, scheme, racket, cmd

I am trying to make a stand-alone Racket executable on the Windows platform. How do I go about running raco from the windows command line? I'm not familiar with it.

If I use the documentation and enter the following command into `cmd.exe`:

> raco exe --gui main.rkt

`cmd.exe` tells me:

> 'raco' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Substituting in `raco.exe` tells me the same thing.

I also tried typing:

> 'C:\Program Files\Racket\raco.exe' exe --gui .\main.rkt

into `powershell` and it gave me an `Unexpected token 'exe' in expression or statement` error.

Comment: Oscar answered the question as you asked it, re using the command line. Just to mention something you probably already know (but someone else might not): Another way to make an executable is in DrRacket. From the **Racket** menu choose **Create Executable**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem: you need to add to windows' %PATH% (an environment variable) the path to the executable. For the second problem: check the correct syntax for the `exe` command, and/or the "--gui" modifier, they're being misused. For instance, try this after solving the first problem:

```
$ raco.exe exe main.rkt
```

The above will create an executable `main.exe` file.

Comment: I have the same problem: raco says "Unrecognized command: exe".

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Racket, which includes DrRacket. (Of course, you’re welcome to use your preferred text editor, but the tutorials will assume you’re using DrRacket.)

Update the PATH envi­ron­ment vari­able on your system to include the direc­tory that holds the racket appli­ca­tion. On Mac OS and Linux, this path will be some­thing like "/path/to/racket/bin". On Windows, it’ll be some­thing like "C:\Program Files\Racket". Then, from the terminal, you’ll be able to run racket and raco (see raco: Racket Command-Line Tools).

Windows users who haven’t altered your PATH before: don’t panic. To add the Racket command-line programs to your Windows 10 PATH, click the Windows search box, type the word path, and then click on Edit the system environment variables. Click on the Environment Variables button. In the top window, which contains your user variables, find Path and double-click it to open. Click the New button and either use the Browse button to select your Racket directory, or manually enter its path. Restart your Windows terminal (either the Command Prompt or PowerShell) and now racket and raco should work.